# Error - reading DHCP configuration file. No such file or directory. Solaris 10

Tags: unix, solaris, dhcp-server

I'm currently working on a Sparc Sun-Fire-280R running Solaris 10 8/10. The machine has dhcp-server preconfigured to use NIS from the onset but I don't have any knowledge of where those config files are stored. I have tried all sorts like changing the resource type from SUNWbinfiles to SUNWfiles etc, but haven't had much luck.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
root@host # dhcpconfig -C -p /var/dhcp -r SUNWfiles
dhcpconfig: Error - reading DHCP configuration file. No such file or directory

root@host # dhcpconfig -U -hx
Unconfigure will stop the DHCP service and remove the DHCP configuration file.
Are you SURE you want to unconfigure the DHCP service? ([Y]/N): y
dhcpconfig: Error - reading DHCP configuration file. No such file or directory
root@host # dhcpconfig -S -r 
dhcpconfig: Error - failed to read DHCP server parameters.

root@host # pntadm -L

Warning: No DHCP configuration file exists. There is no way to verify the
data store version for this operation.

pntadm: null is not a valid resource.
root@host # pntadm -R

Warning: No DHCP configuration file exists. There is no way to verify the
data store version for this operation.

root@host # svcs | grep dhcp-server
offline        3:54:11 svc:/network/dhcp-server:default
```

Please help me. How can I reconfigure dhcp-server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with this:

**check if the file /etc/inet/dhcpsvc.conf exists. If it doesn't create it**

**Restart DHCP server**

```
dhcpconfig -S -r
```

**Re-configure dhcp server**

```
dhcpconfig -C -p /var/dhcp -r SUNWfiles
```

**Unconfigure it**

```
dhcpconfig -U -hx
```

**check configuration details (just to be sure)**

```
dhtadm -P
```

**Re-configure it**

```
dhcpconfig -D -r SUNWfiles -p /var/dhcp -h dns -y 192.168.x.xx -l 480 -d 192.168.x.xx -a 192.168.x.xx
```